# Oracle Having > Single Row

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having

I have an Oracle query, which has something to the effect of

Having Count(field) > (Long SQL statement that returns one row)
Both sides of the query work alone, but together I get a "not a group by" expression.

When replacing the long SQL statement with a number it works, but I assumed the two were equivalent if only one row is returned?

**Edit**
After doing some playing around I realized:
... Table T ... Having Count(field) > (Long SQL statement with Table A Where A.field = T.field)
It works when I replace T.field with any of the specific options for T.field, but when I reference T.field specifically I get the same "not a group by expression"

Comment: Can you post your query? This works for me `SELECT DUMMY FROM dual GROUP BY DUMMY  HAVING COUNT(DUMMY ) > (select 1 from dual);`

Comment: I can't post my exact query, but I realize I might have been looking at the wrong part of it for the problem @Martin

Comment: Solved. My pre > statement apparently needs to have T.field within the group by. I'm not sure why the worked alone but not in conjunction with one another.

Comment: If you posted examples of what worked and what did not (with fake field names, not your original query), someone could explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ... 
FROM Table T ...
GROUP BY T.afield
HAVING Count(T.anotherfield) 
       > (Long SQL statement with Table A Where A.somefield = T.afield)
```

should work ok.

---

```
SELECT ... 
FROM Table T ...
GROUP BY T.anotherfield
HAVING Count(T.anotherfield) 
       > (Long SQL statement with Table A WHERE A.somefield = T.afield)
```

should not work. A field (like `T.afield`) that is not included in the `GROUP BY` list, cannot be referenced in `SELECT`, `HAVING` or `ORDER BY` clauses. Only aggregate functions of that field can be referenced - you could have `WHERE A.somefield = MIN(T.afield)` for example.

Answer (score 1):

When Oracle parses your query it doesn't know if the query is going to return only one row or a bunch of rows.  So simply append `group by your_column` to the end of your query.

For example this query returns one row:

```
select count(*) from user_objects;
```

But if I wanted to include sysdate along with that, I would have to do

```
select 
    sysdate the_date, 
    count(*) 
from
    user_objects 
group by 
    the_date;
```

Comment: I formatted your code for you. This can be done by selecting your code and pressing the `{}` button.